# Set Braintree payment information to credit card

Tags: magento2, credit-card, braintree

I'm using Braintree sandbox. This is what I'm sending to `POST /guest-carts/:quote/payment-information`:

```
email: '<my-email>',
paymentMethod: {
    method: 'braintree',
    additional_data: {
        cc_cid: '123',
        cc_type: 'VI',
        cc_exp_year: '2020',
        cc_exp_month: '1',
        cc_number: '4111111111111111'
    }
}
```

I'm constantly getting this response:

```
{
    "message": "Transaction has been declined. Please try again later."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact).</sub>

It might be useful to post the version of Magento2 you're using as it's possible one of a few conflating errors could be at play here.

However, one thing that the issue might be is that the *amount* of the transaction (presumed by the error message which itself could be thrown inappropriately but we'll leave that assumption in place for now) itself.

Transactions between [2000-3000 will cause a processor decline](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/ruby#test-amounts) with an unsuccessful result in the sandbox environment. Alternatively your Braintree sandbox account could have one of a few fraud rules in place that is being triggered here as well. I'd recommend checking the transactions in your Braintree sandbox account via the [control panel](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login) to see what the transaction's statuses are.